# How to search for multiple strings and keep counters for them

Tags: c#, search

What I'm trying to do is the following - I have hundreds of log files, that I need to search through and do some counting. The basic idea is this, take a `.txt` file, read every line, if search item 1 is found, increment the counter for search item 1, if search item 2 is found, increment the counter for search item 2 and so on.. For example, if the file contained something like...

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
j k h
```

And If I specified the `searchables` to be `e` & `h`, the output should say

```
e : 1
h : 2
```

The number of search terms is expandable, basically the user can give either 1 search number or 10, so i'm not sure how I can implement n number of counters based on the number of searchables.

The below is what I have so far, its just a basic approach to see what works and what doesnt... Right now, it only keeps the count for one of the search terms. At the moment, I am writing the results to the console to just test, ultimately, It will be written to a `.txt` or `.xlsx`. any help will be appreciated!

```
string line;
int Scounter = 0;
int Mcounter = 0;
List<string> searchables = new List<string>();

private void search_Log(string p)
{
    searchables.Add("S");
    searchables.Add("M");

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(p);
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < searchables.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (line.Contains(searchables[i]))
            {
                Scounter++;                     
            }
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("# of S: " + Scounter);
    Console.WriteLine("# of M: " + Mcounter);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common approach to this is to use a `Dictionary<string, int>` to track the values and counts:

```
// Initialise the dictionary:
Dictionary<string, int> counters = new Dictionary<string, int>();
```

Then later:

```
if (line.Contains(searchables[i]))
{
    if (counters.ContainsKey(searchables[i]))
    {
        counters[searchables[i]] ++;
    }
    else
    {
        counters.Add(searchables[i], 1);
    }
}
```

Then, when you are finished processing:

```
// Add in any searches which had no results:
foreach (var searchTerm in searchables)
{
    if (counters.ContainsKey(searchTerm) == false)
    {
         counters.Add(searchTerm, 0);
    }
}

foreach (var item in counters)
{
     Console.WriteLine("Value {0} occurred {1} times", item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: How to print the count after counting is done for each search term?

Comment: iterate `counters.Values` to print

Comment: This is probably the best answer. Im assuming that iterating through a dictionary is faster than iterating through a list of objects, and since there are potentially hundreds of files and you are iterating through on each line of each file, the potential performance increase could be relatively substantial. Am I correct that dictionaries are faster?

Comment: Dictionaries internally use a hashtable for lookups: they are relatively expensive to create, but then each lookup is fast.

Comment: check edit, I tried your method and it worked, but when I called the function again on a second file, I got wrong counts, not sure why? do you see anything wrong?

Comment: @sparta93 Your code (and mine) counts the number of lines which have the search terms in them, it does not count the number of occurrences of the search term within the line. Is that what you want?

Comment: @stuartd actually, nevermind. I got confused with something else. Your solution works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of linq here:

```
string lines = reader.ReadtoEnd();

var result = lines.Split(new string[]{" ","\r\n"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                  .GroupBy(x=>x)
                  .Select(g=> new 
                              { 
                                  Alphabet = g.Key , 
                                  Count = g.Count() 
                               }
                          );
```

### Input:

> > a b c 
> >     d e f

Output :

> > a: 1  
> >        b: 1  
> >        c: 1  
> >        d: 1  
> >        e: 1  
> >        f: 1

Answer (score 2):

you could use a class for the searchables like:

```
public class Searchable
{
     public string searchTerm;
     public int count;
}
```

then

```
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    foreach (var searchable in searchables)
    {
        if (line.Contains(searchable.searchTerm))
        {
            searchable.count++;                     
        }
    }
}
```

This would be one of many ways to track multiple search terms and their counts.

Comment: This is ok, but if the line contains the searchTerm more than once it won't count the extras, it only allows for a search term to be encountered once per line.

Answer (score 1):

This version will count 1^n search terms that occur 1^n times per file line.  It accounts for the possibility of a term existing more than once on one line.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Func<string, string[], Dictionary<string, int>> searchForCounts = null;
            searchForCounts = (filePathAndName, searchTerms) =>
            {
                Dictionary<string, int> results = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePathAndName) || !File.Exists(filePathAndName))
                    return results;
                using (TextReader tr = File.OpenText(filePathAndName))
                {
                    string line = null;
                    while ((line = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < searchTerms.Length; ++i)
                        {
                            var searchTerm = searchTerms[i].ToLower();
                            var index = 0;
                            while (index > -1)
                            {
                                index = line.IndexOf(searchTerm, index, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                                if (index > -1)
                                {
                                    if (results.ContainsKey(searchTerm))
                                        results[searchTerm] += 1;
                                    else
                                        results[searchTerm] = 1;
                                    index += searchTerm.Length - 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return results;
            };
            var counts = searchForCounts("D:\\Projects\\ConsoleApplication5\\ConsoleApplication5\\TestLog.txt", new string[] { "one", "two" });
            Console.WriteLine("----Counts----");
            foreach (var keyPair in counts)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Term: " + keyPair.Key.PadRight(10, ' ') + " Count: " + keyPair.Value.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}

Input:
OnE, TwO

Output:
----Counts----
Term: one        Count: 7
Term: two        Count: 15
```

Comment: This would only fail to count a term if your search term has a line break in it e.g "I am on\nTwo Lines"

This is also case insensitive and it won't count matching terms found in the text file regardless of the casing uses on the search terms.  So if you search for two terms "One" and "ONE" they will be in the results as just "one" and combined counts.